# Are questions about apache and mod_wsgi configuration on topic on DevOps?

Tags: discussion

I was thinking to ask a series of questions about apache and mod_wsgi configuration, their performance and memory - would this kind of questions be on topic here or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) is a better place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only about apache and mod_wsgi performance with no relation with any devops culture or tooling, that's clearly better suited on ServerFault in my opinion.